# What is the best way to edit a settings file containing a global named config in php

Tags: php, settings, global

I've got the file 'init.php'. This one is being used to start the session, set some settings and that sort of stuff. I call to this file using this line:

```
require_once 'core/init.php';
```

This works perfectly in my opinion. Now, I've written the following script so that it becomes very easy to call a setting in the init.php file.

```
class Config {
    public static function get($path = null) {
        if ($path){
            $config = $GLOBALS['config'];
            $path = explode('/', $path);

            foreach($path as $bit) {
                if(isset($config[$bit])) {
                    $config = $config[$bit];
                }
            }    
            return $config;
        }    
        return false;
    }
}
```

So now I can use this line of code in my other pages to use the setting:

```
Config::get('settings/main_color')
```

This is very easy of course. But now I'd like to edit a setting without having to change the file myself. It should all be done by scripts in the browser. The rest of my init.php settings global looks like this:

```
$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
    'mysql' => array(
        'host' => 'localhost:3307',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'usbw',
        'db' => 'webshop'
    ),
    'remember' => array(
        'cookie_name' => 'hash',
        'cookie_expiry' => 604800
    ),
    'sessions' => array(
        'session_name' => 'user',
        'token_name' => 'token'
    ),
    'settings' => array(
        'main_color' => '#069CDE',
        'front_page_cat' => 'Best Verkocht,Populaire Producten',
        'title_block_first' => 'GRATIS verzending van &euro;50,-',
        'title_block_second' => 'Vandaag besteld morgen in huis!',
    ),
    'statics' => array(
        'header' => 'enabled',
        'title_block' => 'enabled',
        'menu' => 'enabled',
        'slideshow' => 'enabled',
        'left_box' => 'enabled',
        'email_block' => 'enabled',
        'footer' => 'enabled',
        'keurmerken' => 'enabled',
        'copyright' => 'enabled'
    )
);
```

What I hope for is a solution like this:

```
Config::update('settings/main_color','blue')
```

What is the best way to achieve this? Use str_replace and replace the word in the file? I hope there's a better way of doing this, and I'd be very pleased if you could help me out.

EDIT: (my complete init.php file)

```
<?php
session_start();

define('DS',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

$GLOBALS['config'] = json_decode(__DIR__.DS.'prefs.json', true);

spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
});

require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';
require_once 'functions/statics.php';
require_once 'functions/pagination.php';

if(Cookie::exists(Config::get('remember/cookie_name')) && !Session::exists(Config::get('sessions/session_name'))) {
    $hash = Cookie::get(Config::get('remember/cookie_name'));
    $hashCheck = DB::getInstance()->get('users_session', array('hash', '=', $hash));

    if($hashCheck->count()) {
        $user = new User($hashCheck->first()->user_id);
        $user->login();
    }
}

$_link = DB::getConnected();

$url_parts = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$current = $url_parts[count($url_parts)-2];

if($current == 'page'){
    $_SESSION['location'] = 1;
}
else{
    $_SESSION['location'] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is somewhat opinion-based, but I use a json or xml file that the config file parses. The `update` would call the file, parse it then resave it.

**/core/init.php**

```
$GLOBALS['config'] = json_decode(__DIR__.DS.'prefs.json', true);
```

**/core/prefs.json**

> {"mysql":{"host":"localhost:3307","username":"root","password":"usbw","db":"webshop"},"remember":{"cookie_name":"hash","cookie_expiry":604800},"sessions":{"session_name":"user","token_name":"token"},"settings":{"main_color":"#069CDE","front_page_cat":"Best Verkocht,Populaire Producten","title_block_first":"GRATIS verzending van €50,-","title_block_second":"Vandaag besteld morgen in huis!"},"statics":{"header":"enabled","title_block":"enabled","menu":"enabled","slideshow":"enabled","left_box":"enabled","email_block":"enabled","footer":"enabled","keurmerken":"enabled","copyright":"enabled"}}

**Pseudo-code for your update:**

```
class Config
    {
        public static function update($path,$value)
            {
                # Fetch the file and convert it to json
                $file = json_decode(file_get_contents(CONFIG_PATH),true);
                # Do some code that will update the value....

                # Save file back
                file_put_contents(CONFIG_PATH,json_encode($data));

                # Call your prefs to GLOBALS function here so the settings
                # are updated in your global array
            }
    }
```

Comment: And do you know another way without using JSON?

Comment: XML file but Json is more straightforward

Comment: but does this method (JSON) still work when I'm using my get function?

Comment: Yes because you store the file as json and parse it to array in your ini file.

Comment: Another option is to store some of this data in a database but the connection credentials wouldn't make sense to store in your db. If you want a static prefs file/config, I would do json so you can easily edit it through the interface

Comment: One note, since it's a file now, (your prefs) you will want to make sure you secure the folder it's saved in for read-only by server. You can do that is with directory premissions or by using an `.htaccess` file

Comment: okay, thank you, It's just for a school project, but I'll make it happen. Thank you for this extra advise!

Comment: I am getting an error:
Notice: Use of undefined constant DS - assumed 'DS' in E:\3. School\56\3. Informatica\3. PHP\2. USBWebserver v8.6\root\OOP\System\core\init.php on line 38
Which is your line to define the global config

Comment: Sorry, I define `DS` in a config file ususally. It's a directory separator, `define('DS',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);` it's for better compatability. You can use a directory slash (likely a forward slash: `/`)

Comment: Okay, now I've got some other problems. Something goes wrong in the init.php file with the code coming after your lines. This error comes up: 

`Warning: require_once(functions/sanitize.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\3. School\56\3. Informatica\3. PHP\2. USBWebserver v8.6\root\OOP\System\core\init.php on line 46

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'functions/sanitize.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in E:\3. School\56\3. Informatica\3. PHP\2. USBWebserver v8.6\root\OOP\System\core\init.php on line 46`

Comment: Would you like me to show you the complete init.php file or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132033/discussion-between-rasclatt-and-lex-de-willigen).

Comment: can you help me out one more time? See the chat please